# ReactJS ,Webpack : You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am able to bundle react app with webpack.

**ERROR**

```
ERROR in ./src/routes.js
Module parse failed: /home/vivek/Desktop/prismo-front/src/routes.js 
Unexpected token (7:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
| var Routes = (
|       <Router history={browserHistory}>
|           <Route path='/' component={Gallery} />
|       </Router>
@ ./src/index.js 3:0-30
```

**Routes.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Router,Route,browserHistory} from 'react-router'
import Gallery from './pages/gallery'


 var Routes = (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path='/' component={Gallery} />
    </Router>
)

export default Routes
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, '/build');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, '/src');

var config = {
 entry:'./src/index.js',
 output:{
 path:BUILD_DIR,
 filename:'bundle.js'
},
module : {
 loaders : [
  {
    test : /\.jsx?$/,
    include : APP_DIR,
    exclude:path.resolve(__dirname, '/node_modules'),
    loader : 'babel-loader',
    query : {
      presets:['react', 'es2015']
    }
   }
  ]
 }
}
module.exports = config;
```

**package.json**

```
{
 "name": "prismo-front",
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
   "path": "^0.12.7",
   "range-function": "^0.1.1",
   "react": "^15.6.1",
   "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.1",
   "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
   "react-router": "^3.0.5"
  },
 "devDependencies": {
 "react-scripts": "1.0.10",
 "webpack": "^3.3.0",
 "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
 "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
 "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1"
},
"scripts": {
 "start": "react-scripts start",
 "build": "react-scripts build",
 "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
 "eject": "react-scripts eject"
 }
}
```

I have been trying this for a week now. 
I have read docs clearly and everything is written accordingly.
I have the devDependencies in place.
Please Help!!

Comment: In your loader configuration, you only apply it to files located in `APP_DIR`. Are you sure it points to the right path? I would recommend adding `console.log(APP_DIR);` to your config file, just to make sure.

Comment: Yes it reads the same path /src .

    `vivek@vivek:~$ cd Desktop/prismo-front/
     vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/prismo-front$ sudo webpack -d
     [sudo] password for vivek: 
     /src
     Hash: c49dea195a1ee2962f33
     Version: webpack 3.3.0
     Time: 835ms
        Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
        bundle.js  2.07 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
        [81] ./src/index.js 128 bytes {0} [built]
        [183] ./src/routes.js 301 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
        + 182 hidden modules`

/src files are read correctly.

Comment: FWIW, your usage of `path.resolve()` results in incorrect paths (namely `/build` and `/src`, in the root of your file system). They should be `path.resolve(__dirname, './build')` and `path.resolve(__dirname, './src')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with how `APP_DIR` is declared. Change it to

```
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
```

and `webpack` will start loading `jsx` files with `babel` and you won't have this issue anymore. This is because `path.resolve` had set `APP_DIR` to `/src` because it evaluates it's arguments from right to left, stopping at the first encounter of an absolute path. Relevant docs [here](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths). Look at the second example there.

```
path.resolve('/foo/bar', '/tmp/file/');
// Returns: '/tmp/file'
```

However, I can see more issues.

1. Same applies for `BUILD_DIR`
2. You are using `create-react-app`. You don't need to configure webpack and babel separately. CRA does it for you.